# NSURLSession code not working in Xcode7 but the same code works in xcode6

Tags: nsurlsession, xcode7, ios9

I am having some issue with using NSURLSession in Xcode7 and Swift2. For some reason I keep getting NSURLErrordomain error but the same code
is working on Xcode6 with swift 1.2.

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=one%20republic")  
let downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(baseURL!, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in  
  if(error == nil){  
     let objectData = NSData(contentsOfURL: location!)  
     let tmpData :NSString = NSString(data: objectData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!  
     print("success")  
  } else {  
     print("Failed")  
  }            
})  
downloadTask!.resume()
```

[image]

It keeps giving me NSURLDomain Error Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Transport Application Security is described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

You should add the proper exception on a server by server basis, NSAllowsArbitraryLoads just disables AppTransportSecurity completely;
This is discouraged, and eventually could get your app rejected.

You should use NSExceptions only when you can't use proper https on all urls, e.g. when the server is in control of another party, for an already existing app, or if there are technical reasons preventing the server from serving https connections.

You should use forward secrecy exceptions when the server is unable to support the most modern https protocols.

The ATS accepted by default protocols are the following:
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

If your server supports https with these protocols, and the certificates are properly configured, and the TLS version is 1.2, no App Transport Security configuration needs to be added to the info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution its because of the new app transport security.You need to add NSAppTransportSecurity key to the Info.plist as a dictionary with NSAllowsArbitraryLoads property set to true.

[image]

And it should work fine now more here [NSURLSession changes in iOS9](http://shrikar.com/nsurlsession-changes-in-ios9/)